# Poisson Distribution

Tags: statistics, poisson-distribution

Fishes swim by a fisherman at a rate of approximately 3 fishes per hour. The fisherman has 1/2 chance of catching each fish. The fishes arrival rate independent and poisson distributed.

The question is, what the chance that in 4 hours of fishing, our fisherman manages to catch atleast 2 fishes?

My method of solving it is this:

P(atleast 2 fishes) = 1 - P(fisherman gets 0 fishes) - P(fisherman get 1 fish).

The answer that is given to us in the solution is:

$$1 - e^{-6} -6e^{-6}$$

What i am wondering and want an answer from you guys is the following:
What is the equation for 
P(fisherman gets 0 fishes) and
P(fisherman gets 1 fishes)

and how would it look if we wanted to find for for example 3 fishes or "n" fishes?

Comment: Splitting a Poisson process yields again a Poisson process. So consider a Poisson process with rate $3\times\frac12$ here...

Comment: Hmmm... Would you know how to prove that the number of fishes caught in 4 hours is Poisson, as the accepted answer asserts? I mean, not by repeating that it is because somebody told you so, but actually *proving* it? Because if you were given this as homework, this might be the part of the proof your TA is expecting to read from you. :-)

Comment: Is this what they call *an embarassed silence*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a Poisson distribution $p(n)$, where $n$ is the number of fish caught in an interval, with a mean per interval (here the rate of fish, i.e. "fish caught per interval, on average") $\mu=\frac{3}{2} \text{ per hour}\times 4 \text{ hours}=6$ when the interval is $4$ hours. Then the probability of catching $n$ fish in the interval is simply $$p(n)=\frac{\mu^n e^{-\mu}}{n!}$$

Comment: We are catching on average $1/2$ the fish that are passing by at a rate of $3$ per hour, over a $4$ hour interval. $~$ So, fish are caught at an average rate of $6$ fish per four hour interval. $~$ Hence the count of fish caught in the interval is a Poisson Random Variable with parameter $6$: $$X\sim\mathcal{Pois}(6)$$

Comment: @GrahamKemp Whoops, thanks for catching that one! Corrected now.

Comment: This avoids the main point to be explained, which is the appearance of a Poisson(6) random variable or, equivalently, of a Poisson(1.5) process.

Comment: @Did I don't understand your objection, could you elaborate? I have given the answer to the question "how would it look if we wanted to find for for example 3 fish[...] or "n" fish[...]?" - or where is my mistake?

Comment: Giving the result $\ne$ Explaining why it holds. Answering a question requires the latter, not only the former (except in very specific cases, maybe, of which the present question is not an example).

Comment: @Did $\mu$ is *defined* to be "the average number of events in an interval"  [(from the wiki)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution#Probability_of_events_for_a_Poisson_distribution), which is what I calculated to be 6 (for an interval of 4 hours). Do you expect me to derive the formula for the Poisson distribution? That doesn't really seem to be what OP is looking for.

Comment: Obviously this is the thinning operation that requires explanations, in other words the Poisson(3) process is given but one might want to explain where the Poisson(1.5) process comes from. (But if you could stop proposing absurd interpretations for what I precisely explain, I would be thankful.)

Comment: @Did Do you really think that that requires any further explanation though? All you need to do is to calculate the expected number of fish caught in a time interval - why would you want to complicate it? I'm not trying to be rude, I honestly don't understand. Also, perhaps it would be best to let OP ask further questions if s/he doesn't understand the answer, if that's what you are worried about?

Comment: Hello, OP here. What im trying to understand is how 

P(fisherman gets 0 fishes) = e^−6. And how P(fisherman gets 1 fish) = 6e^-6

Comment: @PeterNiklas You know the formula for the poisson distribution, right (it is the one I have written in my answer)? If you insert $\mu=6$ and $n=0$, you get $6^0e^{-6}/0!=e^{-6}$. If you insert $n=1$ instead, you get $6^1e^{-6}/1!=6e^{-6}$. Do you understand how I got to $\mu=6$?

Comment: "Do you really think that that requires any further explanation though?" Yes, the fact that the number of fishes caught by the fisherman is a Poisson process requires a proof (or one knows this beforehand and then there is no point to the present question). "You know the formula for the poisson distribution" Offtopic. "Do you understand how I got to μ=6?" **Finally** something slightly on-topic, if reinterpreted as: Do you understand how I got a Poisson random variable (to be explained) with mean 6 (comparatively easier)?

Comment: @Did "that the number of fishes caught by the fisherman is a Poisson process requires a proof" - it is stated in the problem formulation: "The fishes arrival rate [is] independent and Poisson distributed".

Comment: Quote: "caught by the fisherman". So, actually, you really missed the problem after all.

Comment: @Did The fisherman's chance to succeed doesn't have to be Poisson; it might as well be uniform. All that matters is that it has a mean of one half, because it is only involved in calculating $\mu$. And I suggest you leave out comments like your last sentence - it doesn't really contribute to the conversation, and comes across (at least to me) as rather ad hominem.

Comment: No, the *distribution* of the number of fishes caught by the fisherman is needed, and for that, one needs more than what you say. If I suggest to get an introductory book on Poisson processes and to read it, will you consider it as ad hominem? This would be a pity.

Comment: Oh, and anyway, you *stated* that the number of fishes is Poisson -- and suddenly we do not need this anymore? You lost me.

Comment: @Did You claim it is needed to know the distribution, but I see no argument (or reason) for this. Either way,  I'll stop this conversation here, as I don't suspect it'll lead anywhere.. thanks for the inputs.

Comment: Well, yes, the distribution is needed, for example because the OP asks for it. Indeed, when a discussion has fallen to such a low level, there is not much point to continue it. Next time, try to reach a correct answer instead of displaying such a peculiar rhetorical tactics.

Comment: @Did Well, OP seems to have gotten something out of the answer (strangely enough, since it surely seems like it is *completely* wrong), and that's what I wrote it for, so I'm satisfied with the outcome :)

Comment: Rhetorics again. One feels the OP sure about the mathematical value of their answer...